# Bootstrap NavBar Image Dropdown

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap 14.3 and I am trying to have an image within the NavBar to dropdown a menu when clicked.

I have implemented the below code however the menu pops up at the top of the page and is not aligned under the image.

Does anybody have any suggestions to fix and improve this below solution?

```
    <span uib-dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
      <a href id="simple-dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" class="img-rounded" alt="Rounded Image" style="position: relative;top: 10px;float: left; left: -5px;height:100%;">
      </a>
      <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown" style="">
        <li>
          <a href='/profile'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span> Settings</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

By removing the span and moving uib-dropdown to the li element. It aligned perfectly

```
            <li uib-dropdown style="padding-left:0px;margin-left:0px;">
                    <a href id="simple-dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle class="profile-image dropdown-toggle" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" class="img-rounded" alt="Rounded Image" style="heigth:30px;width:30px;margin-left:0px;padding-left:0px;">
                    </a>
                    <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown" style="">
                        <li>
                            <a href='/profile'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='/sponsored'><span class="fa fa-credit-card"></span> Sponsored</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='/admin'><span class="fa fa-cubes"></span> Admin Console</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='/logout'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul> 
            </li>
```